# Unable to establish websocket connection error getting Firefox console logs using Selenium for Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-java

In my Selenium tests using Firefox I always get an error when I try to get the browser console logs. Same code works fine for Chrome and Edge.

For the tests I am using:

- Firefox 100.0
- geckodriver 0.31
- Selenium 4.1.4

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    
    WebDriver webDriver = WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().create();

    try {
        
        DevTools devTools = ((HasDevTools) webDriver).getDevTools();
        devTools.createSessionIfThereIsNotOne();
        devTools.send(Log.enable());
        devTools.addListener(Log.entryAdded(), logEntry -> System.out.println(logEntry.getText()));

        webDriver.navigate().to("https://stackoverflow.com");

    } finally {
        webDriver.quit();   
    }
}
```

Running the previous snippet will always raise the following errors.

```
JavaScript error: chrome://remote/content/server/WebSocketHandshake.jsm, line 182: Error: The handshake request has incorrect Origin header http://localhost:60734
May 10, 2022 1:32:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Invalid Status code=400 text=Bad Request
java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=400 text=Bad Request
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.abort(WebSocketHandler.java:92)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.handleRead(WebSocketHandler.java:118)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.channelRead(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:78)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:314)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:435)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

```
Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:60734/devtools/browser/69e68eb4-b5c5-45c4-b53f-62023f856b44
Build info: version: '4.1.4', revision: '535d840ee2'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Comment: As far as I know, devtools support only Chrome as of now. We may either use old LogType.PERFORMANCE such entities or wait for BiDi.